# Why we need to check if value equals None?

Tags: python

```
values = [-50, -80, -100]
max_value = None
for i in values:
    if max_value is None or i > max_value:
        max_value = i
```

why we need to include this code `max_value is None`
Let's say we go through the for loop
Loop 1: i = -50. We can't evaluate -50 with None, right?

Comment: `max_value` is set to `None` and evaluated the first time before it is changed.

Comment: Exactly. Need it there to avoid an error.

Comment: So that's only a trick to avoid an error?

Comment: @TheOne, You could call it "a trick", but that's not a technical term. It's a way to make your program work, given `max_value` is initialised as `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you can't compare `int` with `NoneType`, this gives `TypeError`:

```
-50 > None  # TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

So removing the condition will lead your code to break. But, much better, set a minimal starting value, e.g. `-inf`:

```
values = [-50, -80, -100]
max_value = -float('inf')
for i in values:
    if i > max_value:
        max_value = i
```

Of course, for your trivial computation, you can use the built-in `max`:

```
max(values)  # -50
```

Comment: I just want to understand about this None. As you said, we can't compare any value to None because it's simpy None so max_value is None here sounds like a trick to me. it doesn't have any meaning as in "i > 3 or i < 10", right?

Comment: @TheOne, Simply put, Python can't evaluate `-50 > None`, so it gives an error. That makes sense, `None` isn't a numeric type. So that's why your algorithm *checks explicitly first* that your value isn't `None`.

Comment: If so, why "if max_value is not None and i > max_value" doesn't give a correct answer?

Comment: `or` is lazy. In the first iteration, the first condition (`max_value is not None`) is not satisfied, so it moves on to the next. It then tries `-50 > None` and fails.

Comment: Thank you. I think i should always go with list[0] as a maximum value. This None is somewhat vague to me.

Comment: You will encounter `None` very often while programming in Python.

Answer (score 1):

The most idiomatic approach is to assume `values[0]` as the maximum and start iterating from the first index:

```
values = [-50, -80, -100]
max_value = values[0]
for i in values[1:]:
    if i > max_value:
        max_value = i
```

And you can get rid of the `None` check.

Comment: To be honest, i always set the first element in the list as a maximum value. But this None thing confused me.

Comment: @TheOne if `max_value` is None, then `i > max_value` is not defined. Hence the check. But setting to the first element is the accepted method of initialisation.